# Rails Having a error after creating new table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, has-many-through, has-many

(Sorry for my english) 
Hello,I create a new post for my error to explain more clearly what's happen
I added a table " user-activities " which allows me to know if a user saw an activity or not
Here is a representation of my DB

[image: DB]
My problem is that I can not create an article anymore
Apparently the problem appears in the save :

Logs :

```
Started POST "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-24 17:21:49 +0200
Processing by ActivitiesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cq573getfK9HBo4U9xiftsdtmScb08A28AWCcwTq2+Csn7u2hmylpjMdaB5qtJ6ZfWoHV/TZ+zF0xtgPCCp69Q==", "activity"=>{"title"=>"Activity 1 ", "content"=>"<p>dzdzqdqzdqz</p>", "group_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Créer l'activité"}
  User Load (4.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
  Group Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)

#activities_controller.rb:9 =>     if @activity.save
```

Controller :

```
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    @activity.user = current_user
    if @activity.save
      flash[:notice] = "Votre activité a été créée !"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Erreur lors la création"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

the controller has not changed when i add the new table and the form to create new activity does not contain an error ( Group id / user IS / content /title /date etcc.. are valid)

it's my models that have changed :

**BEFORE**

*Activity model :*

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

*user-model :*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :activities
end
```

**AFTER :**

*Activity model :*

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_activities
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :group
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

*User-activity model:*

```
class UserActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :user    
end
```

*user-model :*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :user_activities
  has_many :activities, through: :user_activities

end
```

Thanks :)

Comment: this piece of code `validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :activity }` limits the number of pairs user-activity by one. That means that if you already had an activity associated with your user, you won't be able to add more activities to that user

Comment: @seethrough deleted line but the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During development it can have to replace like `@activity.save` with `@activity.save!` and get an exception with more details on the error you have.